# reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'NSManagedObject' must have a valid NSEntityDescription?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsentitydescription

I am getting error in core data x code8.3, Data base is added DB.

Error is.....

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class
>   'NSManagedObject' must have a valid NSEntityDescription

App Name : GPSLocation

Database Name : `GPSLocationDataBase` (Data base created middle of the project)

Entity Name : `GPSLocationEntity`

Comment: Please paste the code how you create a new `GPSLocationEntity `

Comment: The other question is gone

Answer (score 2):

Are you created the NSPersistentContainer with the `GPSLocationDataBase` name? Like

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "GPSLocationDataBase")
```

?
A persistentContainer with different name can cause this issue.

In Obj-C:

```
NSPersistentContainer *container = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName: @"GPSLocationDataBase"];
```

Comment: can u please send the code in objective c

Comment: @Marking: Obj-c version added. Please, add more info to your question

Comment: @Marking: Let me know whether it helped or not (if this was the solution, then please mark it as correct answer)

Comment: no sir it's not helped me, but thank u for your reply to me.....